# Can I display AdSense ads in a mobile app?

Tags: google-adsense

Does Google allow AdSense ads to be displayed in a mobile app, or is it only for web pages? I heard that people were banned for displaying AdSense ads in mobile apps.

I'm asking because I recently upgraded from legacy AdMob to the new AdMob, which has AdSense and AdWords.

Answer (score 1):

You should use AdMob to display ads on mobile applications and AdSense for websites I'm guessing.

AdMob gives you an ID for each ad you want to show in your app and this ID is used to request ads to load inside the app as a banner, etc... AdSense is linked to AdMob account to get your AdMob revenue and add it to the AdSense account so you can withdraw this. Just like YouTube revenue is sent to your AdSense account, AdMob revenue is also sent to the AdSense account to withdraw.

Comment: The legacy Admob don't need Adsense account?

Comment: The upgraded admob so it works with adsense. They tryna combine everything together. I got a letter in a post from google to confirm ny address aswell. They r changing a lot if thing.

Comment: Can i close Adsense while maintaining Admob account or just block Adsense ads?

Comment: You should use admob to display ads on mobile applications and adsense for websites im guessing.

Comment: Now Google has mixed them up. How do i separate them?

Comment: Dont think that can be done now... google linked the accounts together to show all the data in adsense. Must be a reason behind it but according to my knowledge theres not a way to separate it after the new admob update. You can still see admob data by going to the admob website separately but I dont think theres a way to see the adsense data alone unless you can tweak the options given on the adsense website.